# Matrix Calculus question: Taking the derivative of the following equation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus

I am encountering matrix calculus for the first time, and I'm completely lost on the following problem:

I'm trying to get the derivative of $$ (x-\mu)^T F (x - \mu) -1 =0  $$ where $x = (I+2\lambda F )^{-1} (y + 2 \lambda F \mu)$ which transforms the function to the following:

$$((I+2\lambda F )^{-1} (y + 2 \lambda F \mu) - \mu ) ^T F ((I+2\lambda F )^{-1} (y + 2 \lambda F \mu) - \mu ) -1 = 0$$

My intuition tells me that the gradient is just the following (extrapolating from the example of x)

$$ \nabla f(\lambda) = 2 ((I+2\lambda F )^{-1} (y + 2 \lambda F \mu) - \mu ) ^T F $$

In this case, we have $\lambda$ to be scalar, $\mu$ and $y$ are vectors and $F \succcurlyeq 0 $

Which seems to be incorrect, can someone shed light on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Please explain what all these things are. Matrices, vectors, scalars ? What are finally the variables of the function you differentiate ? I believe when you clarify this for yourself this will ultimately answer the question by using the multivariate chain rule.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity I just edited the original question. I am not too sure what extra operations need to be done, and how to do them, as the term above is missing, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\x{(x-\mu)}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\d{\dot}
\def\A{A^{-\o}}
\def\AD{{\d A}^{-\o}}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
$Use a dot to denote derivatives with respect to $\l$ and note the following rules
$$\eqalign{
\g{(Ab)}{\l} &= \d Ab + A\d b
 \qquad&\big({\rm derivative\:of\:a\:product}\big) \\
\d c &= 0
 \qquad&\big({\rm derivative\:of\:a\:constant}\big) \\
\d\l &= \o \\
}$$
The derivative of a matrix inverse is tricky, but follows directly from these rules
$$\eqalign{
I &= A\A \qquad&\big({\rm a\:matrix\:product}\big) \\
0 &= \d A\A + A\,\AD
 \qquad&\big(I\:{\rm is\:a\:constant}\big) \\
\AD &= -\A\d A\A  
 \qquad&\big({\rm solve\:for\:}\AD\big) \\
}$$
For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
A &= I+2\l F,\qquad  &\d A = 2F \\
b &= y+2\l F\mu,\qquad &\d b = 2F\mu \qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$
Now we can differentiate $x$
$$\eqalign{
x &= {\A b} \\
\d x &= \A\d b - \A\d A\A b \\
 &= \A(2F\mu) - \A(2F){\A b} \qquad\qquad \\
 &= 2\A F(\mu-x) \\
}$$
Differentiating the main function yields
$$\eqalign{
f &= \x^T F\x - \o \\
\d f &= \d x^T F\x + \x^T F\d x \qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$
Assuming that $F$ is symmetric, this can be simplified to
$$\eqalign{
\d f &= 2\,\x^T F\d x \\
 &= 4\,\x^T F\A F(\mu-x) \qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

- From
  $$
  G(x):=(x-\mu)^\top F(x-\mu)=\sum_{ij}(x_i-\mu_i)F_{ij}(x_j-\mu_j)
  $$
  we get, by the product rule,
  $$\tag{1}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}G(x)=\sum_{j\not=i}F_{ij}(x_j-\mu_j)+2F_{ii}(x_i-\mu_i)\,.
  $$
- Writing
  $$
  (I+2\lambda F)\,x(\lambda)=y+2\lambda F\mu
  $$
  we get, by differentiating w.r.t. $\lambda$,
  $$
  2F\,x(\lambda)+(I+2\lambda F)\,\dot{x}(\lambda)=2F\mu\,.
  $$
  This gives
  $$\tag{2}
  \dot{x}(\lambda)=(I-2\lambda F)^{-1}2F(\mu-x(\lambda))\,.
  $$
- The function you want to differentiate is $f(\lambda)=G(x(\lambda))$ which maps a scalar to a scalar.
- By the chain rule we finally get
  $$
  \dot{f}(\lambda)=\sum_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}G(x(\lambda))\,\dot{x}_i(\lambda)
  $$
  for the derivative you are seeking. Use (1) and (2) to write this out.